# How to compare correlations

Tags: correlation

In R I have a dataset `data` for each day a week, ie 7 datasets. For the Monday I have data_monday which gives

```
promotions   views
41           231
7            11
120          236
...
```

I get similar output for the other days a week. In R I have calculated the correlation between promotion and views. For example for `data_monday` we get

```
cor.test(data_monday[,1], data_monday[,2], alternative="greater",method="pearson")
```

and this gives me a low p-value, ie we have significant positive correlation and we also get an estimate of the correlation - in this case it's 0.494.

For all the days we have positive correlation **but** we have different values of the correlation. For example Sunday we have an estimated correlation at only 0.291.

My question is this: How can I compare the correlation-values and use it to determine that some days a week have a higher correlation than others? For example one can say that Monday we have a significant higher correlation than Sunday and therefore we should use more money on making the `promotion` higher than Sunday.

**Update**

Using the advise from the second answer the Peason correlation I get and confident interval but I can't see how to use this to **compare** the correlations. For example Friday gives me this

```
cor.test(data_friday[,1],data_friday[,2],alternative="greater",methid="pearson")
```

and this gives me this output

```
        Pearson's product-moment correlation

 t = 7.1374, df = 60, p-value = 7.29e-10
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5445291 1.0000000
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.6776269
```

I want to use Fisher r to z transform to calculate this in R using the packages

```
library(psych)
```

I'm not sure how to calculate this in R.

**My Answer**

This is how I would compare the correlation and draw my conlsusion:

In R I have this function

```
diff.corr <- function( r1, n1, r2, n2 ){ 

Z1 <- 0.5 * log( (1+r1)/(1-r1) ) 
Z2 <- 0.5 * log( (1+r2)/(1-r2) ) 

diff   <- Z1 - Z2 
SEdiff <- sqrt( 1/(n1 - 3) + 1/(n2 - 3) ) 
diff.Z  <- diff/SEdiff 

p <- 2*pnorm( abs(diff.Z), lower=F) 
cat( "Two-tailed p-value", p , "\n" ) 
  }
```

For Monday I have `r1=0.494` and `n1=60`, and for Sunday I have `r2=0.291` and `n2=60`. Then `diff.corr(r1=0.494,n1=60,r2=0.291,n2=60)` which give a two-tailed p-value at 0.19, ie there is no significant difference in the correlations. If the p-value was very low there had been a significant difference between the two correlations.

Is my answer and argument **valid**?

Comment: Regarding the practical application of your results, beware that higher correlation between promotions and views doesn't mean more views by promotion. It just means that promotions have a larger influence compared with other sources of variation, but it can ever happen that more promotion causes less views with a large correlation. I suggest checking for regression coefficients, too.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your last sentence, drawing predictive conclusions this way requires more information about the population and the sampling.  Have you established that the results on each day of the week are independent of every other day?  Lets say you have a promotion on Sunday that gives you an incentive to look on Monday instead.  In this case, any increased slope, correlation, etc. observed on Monday would be dependent on the promotion on Sunday.  This implies that we shouldn't assume there is anything more than a correlation here, as the Sunday event could be a confounding variable.  If I'm understanding your question correctly and your day-of-the-week samples are truly independent, you could apply the Fisher r-to-z transformation as shown here to determine the statistical significance of the difference between the two correlations (i.e. what is the probability that they would occur when there is no relationship between the phenomena):  http://vassarstats.net/rdiff.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - do you know how the two-tailed p-value is calculated in R (from the link you gave) ?

Comment: I would follow the method suggested by Bernhard below, using cor.test.  Source code & documentation can be found here:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.test.html    This page may also be useful:  http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/pValues.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with linear regression instead of Kendall tau, than try Pearson correlation or linear regression. `cor.test` used for pearson will give you a 95% confidence intervall for the regression coefficient and linear regression will give you confidence intervalls for the coefficients and you could test the significants of dummy variables for the days.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How exactly should one test it for a dummy variable for the days?